# Path for jquery ajax for reading a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I use this to read a json file stored on my server:

```
 $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:path,
    contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    dataType:"json"
    success:function(response)
    {
       console.log(response);
       //stuff...
    }  
 });
```

I have tried specifying the path as `MyProject/build/web/leaflet/temp/xyz.json` and as `build/web/leaflet/xyz.json`.

In both the cases I get a response of `404`.

I have tried with both paths using `$.getJSON`,I find that the error occurs when the `readyState` of the `XMLHttpRequest` is `1`.

How should I specify the path for getting the json file?

Comment: Use quotes properly mate.

Comment: add file:// infront of your path , as you will have to specify protocol in front of file-path

Comment: just remove `contentType` for gods sake...

Comment: `contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",` makes no sense at at all. You don't have any POST data to describe the content type of.

Comment: I was typing the code in,not copying it...my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relative URI in JS in the browser needs to be relative to the HTML document that is hosting the JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Add / before your path and have a try.

ex: /MyProject/build/web/leaflet/temp/xyz.json or /build/web/leaflet/xyz.json